# How to draw border with half half colors

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

In the below code how can I draw the line around the circle so that half be blue half red (two color circle border)?

`\node[circle, draw=blue,line width=.5mm] at (0, 0) [label=center:{($A$)}]  (A) {};`

Comment: Try to draw two semi-circles with different colours? B.t.w., the circle *is* the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what `dash patterns` are for. Here are some basic examples.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[circle, draw=blue,dash pattern=on pi*0.5em off pi*0.5em,
postaction={draw=red,dash phase=pi*0.5em},
,line width=.5mm,minimum size=1em] at (0, 0) [label=center:{($A$)}]  (A) {};
\node[circle, draw=blue,dash pattern=on pi*1em off pi*1em,
postaction={draw=red,dash phase=pi*1em},
,line width=.5mm,minimum size=2em] at (2, 0) [label=center:{($A$)}]  (A) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Obviously you can make this a style. (Please let me know if this is to be spelled out.)

Comment: Why are there 0 scores for these answers? :-( very nice.

Answer (score 1):

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[line width=.5mm]
\draw[red] (-0.5,0) arc (180:0:0.5);
\draw[blue] (0.5,0) arc (360:180:0.5);
\node {$(A)$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]